# Changin hyperlink color with text section

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

My writings are linked to the `hyperlinks` above via ID.
Now I want that when I am inside a section of text the hyperlink that my text is connected to will turn red in color.
how to do it?

```css
#personal-loan ul li a:active {
  color: #61B576;
}
```

```html
<section id="service-details">
  <div id="personal-loan">
    <h3>Personal Loans</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#how-payday">How a Payday Loan Online Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#loan-application">Payday Loan Application Processing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-loan">What You Know About Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service-render">What Services We Render</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="personal-loan-text">
    <div id="how-payday" class="personal-loan-text-child-one">
      <h1>How a Payday Loan Online Works</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Egestas at eu purus eleme nergtum. Nisl turpis consectetur amet, nam arc fermentum quam odio eros sem. Morbi mattis eu dictum malesuada. Tellus in.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="loan-application" class="personal-loan-text-child-two">
      <h2>Payday Loan Application Processing</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Interest may vary, be fixed, or mixed, will on the lender’s and characteristics</li>
        <li>Depending on the granting institution and the amount of the loan, goods</li>
        <li>The loan can be granted to anyone, as long as they make the loan application</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="about-loan" class="personal-loan-text-child-three">
      <h3>What You Know About Loans</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jgAsPXRhTLQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="service-render" class="personal-loan-text-child-four">
      <h4>What Services We Render</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ultrices accumsan ultricies morbi purus dui pharetra, diam congue. Facilisi sapien eros, a sagittis, at quam dolor elit. Malesuada </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want when someone scrolls to a text the color of the hyperlink connected to that text will change.

Comment: You'd need to use either JavaScript or, possibly, [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has); but I'm not entirely sure that `:has()` would solve this problem without JavaScript since the UI is dependant on the `href` attribute-value.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're not going to be able to do this without JS. If you want to change the color of a link if the mouse is hovering in a section or when that section is on the screen you'll need JS. The first option would require tracking the mouse and adding a class to the link if it's hovering the same section. The second would use intersection observer and work like this: https://www.bram.us/2020/01/10/smooth-scrolling-sticky-scrollspy-navigation/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to check which link is clicked by looping over all the links in ul tag.

```js
// selecting all links with query selector
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".links")

// looping through all link to check for click event
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      remove() // to remove active class from previous click
      link.classList.add("active");
  })
});

function remove () {
  links.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

Instead of using a:active you can use a.active (active class will be added by javascript after click)

```css
#personal-loan ul li a.active {
        color: #61B576;
      }
      
/* checking for a.active class in anchor link */
```

on each anchor tag you need to add "links" class as mentioned in code.
Their might be other solutions but at the time this is what I've come up with.

```html
    <section id="service-details">
        <div id="personal-loan">
          <h3>Personal Loans</h3>
          <ul>
           <!-- adding links class to all the link you want to change color after click -->
            <li><a class="links" href="#how-payday">How a Payday Loan Online Works</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#loan-application">Payday Loan Application Processing</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#about-loan">What You Know About Loans</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#service-render">What Services We Render</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  
        <div id="personal-loan-text">
          <div id="how-payday" class="personal-loan-text-child-one">
            <h1>How a Payday Loan Online Works</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Egestas at eu purus eleme nergtum. Nisl turpis consectetur amet, nam arc fermentum quam odio eros sem. Morbi mattis eu dictum malesuada. Tellus in.</p>
          </div>
  
          <div id="loan-application" class="personal-loan-text-child-two">
            <h2>Payday Loan Application Processing</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Interest may vary, be fixed, or mixed, will on the lender’s and characteristics</li>
              <li>Depending on the granting institution and the amount of the loan, goods</li>
              <li>The loan can be granted to anyone, as long as they make the loan application</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
  
          <hr>
  
          <div id="about-loan" class="personal-loan-text-child-three">
            <h3>What You Know About Loans</h3>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jgAsPXRhTLQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
  
          <hr>
  
          <div id="service-render" class="personal-loan-text-child-four">
            <h4>What Services We Render</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ultrices accumsan ultricies morbi purus dui pharetra, diam congue. Facilisi sapien eros, a sagittis, at quam dolor elit. Malesuada </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: It is possible just raw css ? I won't javaScript use.

Comment: Did you checked this code? Try it. If that is what you want them I think you can't do without js.... I'm still confused that you want the hyperlink to change color or the section heading that are linked to change the color. Either case you need to use JS as far as I know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You mean when scroll to the section that contain hyperlink text, the text will change to the style that you want? That's sounds very JavaScript xDD

Comment: Yes I want this but it is possible just css ? I don't want to use javaScript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correctly but to achieve this the way I understood it, you could use `a:visited` to change the color of your hyperlink after being cliked once.

```css
a:visited{
  color: green;
}
div{
  height: 600px
}
```

```html
<a href="#title">Link to title</a>
<div></div>
<p id="title">title</p>
```

Comment: You don't understand my problem brother. I want when I scroll change my hyperlink color.